# Redirection in Android studio

Tags: android

How can i redirect to a fragment in bottom navigation by clicking on button in different activity.

My Activity is

```
public class PrescribedMedicine extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textViewback;
private Button btnwishlist;
private Button btncart;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prescribed_medicine);
    textViewback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewback);
    textViewback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnwishlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnwishlist);
    btnwishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i("clicks","you clicked b1 ");
            Intent i=new Intent(
                    PrescribedMedicine.this,
                    MyAccount.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And my fragment code is

```
public class MyAccount extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);`enter code here`
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
      findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
                {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            selectedFragment = Home.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_account:
                            selectedFragment = Account.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                            selectedFragment = MyCart.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                            selectedFragment = WishList.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });

    //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, Home.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();

}
```

}

I have done it for Home fragment but i have to do it for wishlist fragmentand it should be done by clicking button btnwishlist using onclick listener.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Instead of Screenshots of source code, please add it text. Also explain it in detail.

Comment: please read this you will get idea how to post question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wants to redirect to wishlist. i have done it for homefragment  but i can't do it for wishlist fragment

Comment: _i have done it for homefragment but i can't do it for wishlist fragment_. Why ? What is the difference ?

Comment: i don't able to replace the Home instance to Wishlist on clicking button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problemis solved by passing a parameter with intent from the fragment page like.`

```
textViewback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("clicks","you clicked b1 ");
            Intent i1=new Intent(
                    getActivity(),
                    MyAccount.class);
            i1.putExtra("back","account");
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });`
```

and then in activity page getting this parameter as String .`

```
String backyourpriscription = getIntent().getStringExtra("backyourpriscription");
```

and them using.

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
if (Editback != null || backyourpriscription!=null){
        View view = navigation.findViewById(R.id.navigation_account);
        view.performClick();
    }`
```

`Then fragment will change and bottom navigation icon will also change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to MyAccount Activity like in this sample:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PrescribedMedicine.this, MyAccount.class);
intent.putExtra("PARAMETER", "some_parameter");
startActivity(intent);
```

then you can get that parameter in yout MyAccount Activity

```
String parameter = getIntent().getStringExtra("PARAMETER");
```

now if your parameter is not null you can set your WishList fragment

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (parameter !=null){
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, WishList.newInstance());
}else{
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, Home.newInstance());
}
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: The problem is solved but bottom navigation is still at Home any solution for that?